# function with limit equal to infty

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Good day, please I need a function such that f(a) is a finite number but f´(a) tends to infinite, a real number. I see that 1/x or tanx do not satisfy the condition. Thanks.

Comment: Try $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$

Answer (score 1):

Try

$$a=0, \qquad f(x)=\sqrt[3]x$$

Then $f'(x)$ tends to positive infinity as $x$ approaches zero.

Answer (score 1):

Find a function $f(x)$ that has: $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ be finite and existent, but $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$ diverge to infinity.

Plenty of examples, even with simple polynomials.

---

$$f(x)=x^a\to0\text{ as }x\to0\tag{$0<a<1$}$$

$$f'(x)=ax^{a-1}\to+\infty\text{ as }x\to0$$

---

$$g(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}\to0\text{ as }x\to1$$

$$g'(x)=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\to-\infty\text{ as }x\to1$$